# Foreman manifest - Trigger action on Puppet class parameters change

Tags: foreman, puppet-foreman

I am new to Puppet and I do support a small windows environment with mostly web services and console apps, all managed by Foreman/Puppet.

I've managed to write several manifests, which keep those apps up and running fine.

For the Web Console apps, I am struggling to implement the following logic:

If a listening port (variable $port for example) changes (due to a person changing it from the GUI), then trigger a custom script (already in place) to recreate the web service applying the new port in config. (Note: It's not IIS web service, it's native Windows service).

Can somebody please suggest a way how can I handle this?

Thanks upfront!

Regards